# Script to check ntp status and system time sync

Tags: linux, shell-script, ntp, ntpd

Looking for a script to **(1)** check status of ntp and **(2)** if it is within +/- 1 second of a given time server (eg *123.456.789.10*). **(3)** In addition, system time should be checked to see if the timezone is set correctly (eg **PST**)

Here's what I have so far, checking the status of ntp:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -x /usr/bin/ntpstat ]]
then
  echo "ntpstat is NOT installed: please install it"
  exit 3

res=$(/usr/bin/ntpstat)
rc=$?

case $rc in
  0 )
    echo "clocks are synchronized"
    ;;
  1 )
    echo "WARNING: clocks are NOT synchronized"
    ;;
  2 )
    echo "CRITICAL: NTPD IS DOWN -- NO STATUS"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: When I check, I use `ntpdate -q <known ntp server name/IP>` and parse the output to get the actual offset versus that server. This disconnects the "is it good" logic from the script doing the actual data collection so the script doesn't need to be updated or have a parameter changed if we decide to change how tightly a time sync must be in order to be "good"

Comment: Is it for Nagios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `ntpq` for that.

Here's some snippets and pseudo code.

First, calculate the offset and store it in a var:

```
ntp_offset=$(ntpq -pn | \
     /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { offset=1000 } $1 ~ /\*/ { offset=$9 } END { print offset }')
```

1. Server OK when:
   ntp_offset < 1000
2. Server unsynchronised when:
   ntp_offset >= 1000
3. the check for ntpd is down may be done with different approaches, depending on your OS. For example, use `service ntpd status` on red hat, centos and similar, and then check the result status on the `$?` variable.

Comment: The 0, 1, 2 levels suggest it is a Nagios script, and there is a plug-in for that.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, actually the command that I execute is remove from our zabbix configuration.

Comment: Thank you, @NunoPereira .isn't there a correlation between ntpstat and ntpq?

When I try `ntpstat` the output looks like this:
    synchronised to NTP server (10.248.181.16) at stratum 3
    time correct to within 1010 ms
    polling server every 64 s

However, at the exact same time, executing `ntpq -pn` looks like this:

remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
=======================================================
*10.248.181.16   24.56.178.140    2 u   15   64    1    0.261    0.300   0.006

**offset = 0.300**
(Sorry I'm unable to format the comment right)

Comment: Not really, @Cartwig.
Short story: `ntpstat` gives the maximum error that your local clock has, while `ntpq -pn` gives what the local peer estimates as the offset to each of the remote peers. I prefer the second, and the values are very different (offset should be much smaller than the "time correct to within" value).

Check http://serverfault.com/questions/184257/seemingly-poor-quality-of-ntp-time-synchronization-using-a-gps-clock for more info about both.

Comment: **NOTE:** This may not work without telling ntpq to explicitly use IPv4. - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345778/why-does-ntpq-pn-report-connection-refused