# Why does ntpq -pn report "Connection refused"?

Tags: centos, ntp

I've recently setup a CentOS 6.x system with NTPD running and am encountering this error when I run `ntpq -pn`:

```
$ ntpq -pn
ntpq: read: Connection refused
```

I know that `ntpd` is up and functioning via the `ntpstat` command:

```
$ ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (204.11.201.12) at stratum 3
   time correct to within 71 ms
   polling server every 256 s
```

Why is `ntpq -pn` not working?

Comment: Note to self: in my (FreeBSD) case `ntpd` did not run as expected, presumably because the time was so far out – an hour slow. Resolved by using `date` to set them time, then `service ntpd start`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can triage this a bit by looking into the output via `strace` like so:

```
$ strace ntpq -pn ::1|& grep -i conn
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(123), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
recvfrom(3, 0x7fffc3365a10, 516, 0, 0, 0) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
write(2, "Connection refused\n", 19Connection refused
```

Notice that it's using ipv6 to connect. Basically this line:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(123), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
```

Is NTPD listening on a ipv6 port?

```
$ netstat -taupn|grep udp|grep ntp
udp        0      0 10.22.7.237:123             0.0.0.0:*                               24213/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               24213/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               24213/ntpd
```

So it doesn't appear to be listening on ipv6, hence the error. We can work around this by telling `ntpq -pn` to connect explicitly on ipv4 instead like so:

```
$ ntpq -pn 127.0.0.1
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+69.89.207.199   212.215.1.157    2 u  209  256  377   43.582    2.768   0.076
-72.5.72.15      10.3.255.0       3 u  217  256  377   68.627   -1.833   4.388
*204.11.201.12   66.220.9.122     2 u  244  256  377   61.928   -0.712   0.234
+108.59.2.24     130.133.1.10     2 u  178  256  377    1.824    3.256   0.111
```

Much better. And you can confirm our logic using `strace` again:

```
$ strace ntpq -pn 127.0.0.1|& grep -i conn
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Notice that ipv4 uses `sa_family=AF_INET` whereas ipv6 uses `sa_family=AF_INET6` when the `ntpq` client attempts to connect to your `ntpd` via UDP on port 123.

We can also use the `-4` and `-6` switches to `ntpq -pn` as well:

```
$ ntpq -pn -4
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+69.89.207.199   212.215.1.157    2 u  235  256  377   43.582    2.768   0.047
-72.5.72.15      10.3.255.0       3 u  248  256  377   68.627   -1.833   4.417
*204.11.201.12   66.220.9.122     2 u  265  256  377   61.802   -0.765   0.198
+108.59.2.24     130.133.1.10     2 u  212  256  377    1.824    3.256   0.097
```

#### References

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/fuel/+bug/1469239

Comment: Thank I found with your post and https://serverfault.com/questions/573351/why-does-ntp-daemon-keep-listening-on-udp6 that ntp was not listening in ipV6

Comment: It should be `netstat -taup` instead of `netstat -taupn`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue recently with CentOS7. ntpq -p would show 'read: Connection refused', as well as many other commands in ntp debug such as 'clocklist' and some others. NTP servers I set in ntp.conf were being ignored. Here are some other notable outputs:

```
[root@server ~]# ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (69.164.198.192) at stratum 3
   time correct to within 56 ms
   polling server every 1024 s

[root@server ~]# ntpdate
14 Oct 00:02:14 ntpdate[21443]: no servers can be used, exiting

[root@server ~]# systemctl status ntp
Unit ntp.service could not be found.

[root@server ~]# systemctl status ntpd
 ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

ntpq> version
ntpq 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Thu Aug  8 11:48:03 UTC 2019 (1)

ntpq> clocklist
ntpq: read: Connection refused

ntpq> cooked
Output set to cooked

ntpq> readlist
ntpq: read: Connection refused
```

When I checked the IP of the NTP server it was using, it was always something from ARIN(?) or a big provider like Level3. I couldn't choose the server, but the servers it was using looked OK. But it still would not let me choose my own servers no matter what I did in `/etc/ntp.conf`.

I began to suspect I had a bad program somehow, and I started to suspect the epel repository I loaded as I needed some other programs from there.

Sure enough, I performed the following and resolved the issue:

```
yum remove ntp
yum install ntp --disablerepo=epel
```

It reinstalled, now `ntpq -p` works, and `systemctl status ntpd` appears as:

```
[root@server ntpstats]# systemctl status ntpd
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-10-14 22:14:44 CDT; 3s ago
```

Finally the servers I set in `/etc/ntp.conf` are being used.

I don't know how to get word to epel that their CentOS7 ntp is somehow hosed, maybe someone will see this and report.

Note that both epel and the CentOS repository were showing the same version: `ntp-4.2.6p5-29.el7.centos.x86_64`.

Comment: This solved the error with `ntpq -p`, but I still get the same error with `ntpdate`, saying `no servers can be used`. Still, thanks!

Comment: Had to stop `ntpd` before running `ntpdate`, of course :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me.  The following resolved the connection issue:

Edit the /etc/ntp.conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

Find the lines with the servers listed and change to the following:

```
# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.
pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Restart and reload the ntp service.

```
#force-reload the service
sudo systemctl force-reload ntp.service
```